# Autotuning an asymmetric PID Loop utilizing the Relay Method

Tags: temperature, pid-controller

I am currently working on a custom PID autotuner for a temperature controller. My heater is controlled by a relay and I do not have a cooling element. I am struggling to apply the Åström-Hägglund method to my situation, following [this document](http://www.processcontrolstuff.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/relay_autot-2.pdf).

First, the heater block does not function in a symmetric sinusoidal fashion. I do not fully understand how to determine Ku and Pu from this situation.

Second, my relay does not provide the option for a negative step, as seems to be required by Åström-Hägglund. I rely on newton's law of cooling for this part.

How do I account for these discrepancies in my calculation? Is there a better tuning method to attempt?

[My Tuning Profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hrBsb.png) -> This may be compared to the tuning profile in figure 4 on page 2 in the document linked above for further clarification.

Comment: I am having the same trouble, were you able to solve it ? I think estimating the system's heat dissipation when the coil is turned off may be a hint to the solution. In that case amplitude of the relay feedback can be adjusted to be double of the dissipated heat and the relay amplitude would be made symmetric, matching with the assumption of sine wave.

Comment: I was able to reach a more stable position by eliminating the derivative component of the PID loop for this application. Since the heating profile is highly asymmetric, the derivative was making the system unstable by railing the output with the slightest downward change in temperature. 

I would prefer to find a way to have the autotuner estimate the heat dissipation without input from the user. Perhaps the simple solution is to move to a more balanced system by selecting a less powerful heater. I still have lots to learn.

Comment: Here is another link that I have found crucial to the development of my algorithm.  http://brettbeauregard.com/blog/2012/01/arduino-pid-autotune-library/

Comment: I ve figured it out. Simply, you should match the dc gain of the relay feedback signal with the dc gain of the system. The mean value of the relay feedback signal must be equal to autotune set temperature times process gain. Only in this condition you can have a symmetric input and output which satisfies the first fundamental frequency amplitude calculation for the method given in the paper